# Question about parallel execution of printf in a multi-threaded program

Tags: c, multithreading, cmd, parallel-processing

I made a program that sends and receives files between two hosts through multi-thread.

The program works normally, but I am worried about the performance of this program.

I call printf quite a lot to show the information and transfer rate of the file to be transferred to the console. When proceeding without any separate action, there was a problem in that the printf of the two threads overlapped to cover each other's text.

**The result I want**

```
[TCP Server] 1 Client Connected: IP Address=127.0.0.1, Port Number=53423
FileName:HDT.exe, FileSize:79202368
Percent : 100.00%

[TCP Server] 1 client disconnected: IP Address =127.0.0.1, Port Number=53423

// The output of the upper part and the output of the lower part shall be simultaneously performed.

[TCP Server] 2 Client Connected: IP Address=127.0.0.1, Port Number=53425
FileName:HDT.exe, FileSize:79202368
Percent : 100.00%

[TCP Server] 2 client disconnected: IP Address =127.0.0.1, Port Number=53425
```

**But there is this problem**

```
[TCP Server] 1 Client Connected: IP Address=127.0.0.1, Port Number=53209
FileName:HDT.exe, FileSize:79202368
Percent : 90.63%% FileSize:79202368 Address=127.0.0.1, Port Number=53211
Percent : 90.63%
[TCP Server] 1 client disconnected: IP Address =127.0.0.1, Port Number=53209

// The transmission rate of two clients is also output to a cursor that outputs a transmission rate of one client, and the output is messed up.

Percent : 100.00%

[TCP Server] 2 client disconnected: IP Address =127.0.0.1, Port Number=53211
```

So I used CRITICAL_SECTION object like this

```
            EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
            cur.Y = thread_number * 6 + 2; // Cur is a COORD variable that stores zero as an x member.
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Cur); // Move the cursor position of the console before outputting for a smooth output.
            
            // curProgress value is the size of the current file transferred.
            // totalProgress value is stored by receiving the total file size from the other host before the file is transmitted.
            printf("Percent : %2.2f%%", (curProgress / totalProgress) * 100.0f); 
            LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
```

I also called EnterCriticalSection to notify the name of the file to be transferred or that the transfer has ended.

There is no problem with the operation of the program, but I think it is very bad for performance.
Is there really no way to efficiently print out multiple prints on different lines without using lock?
I also tried ANSI commands such as \033[;H, but the problem was not resolved.

Comment: Show the output, because I do not believe that this `printf` call will be thread-unsafe. It also does not print a "line".

Comment: @Cheatah modified the question and added example. In addition, \n is moved to SetConsoleCursorPosition, so I didn't use it because I thought it was unnecessary.

Comment: Well `printf` is supposed to be thread-safe and *none* of the `Percent : 100.00%` look interrupted, so your problem is in the other thread, where you probably use separate `printf` calls, rather than first building a single buffer for a single `printf` to output. But most of the output you show is not outputted by the code you show, so we are still guessing here.

Comment: @Cheatah What does separator printf calls mean? Is there a problem with the output because the printf used by the two threads uses the same buffer?